# Adding 'freehand' data to raster mapping in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

Having just worked out [how to import raster mapping into QGIS at the correct scale](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/how-do-i-import-os-raster-tiles-into-qgis-at-the-correct-scale), I'd like to now add useful information to the map like marked routes, labels etc. How can I do this in a 'freehand' manner, rather than importing existing datasets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an easy simple way:
layer->new-> new shape layer
select correct type point /line /shape and correct projection (Sepcify CRS)
now: toogle editing
digitize = "draw"
toggle editing to save

[image]

Comment: I just discovered this myself, but thanks! I need to ask another, related question now...

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new vector layer, and adding the features by clicking on the canvas at the right location is probably what you want.

Once finished with your decoration, you can convert the vector to raster, and merge it with your OS background.